# Oracle Database Migration From 10.2.0.4.0 To 12.1.0

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, database-migration, oracle12c

I want to migrate my database from 10g to 12c. The size of the database is over 450 GB. Do I have to upgrade the 10g database to 12c first ? or I can simply copy data from 10g to 12 using expdp/impdp or Transportable tablespace ? Also can I uses Transportable Database feature? I am migrating the database from old Linux server to a new Linux server. Current OS is RHEL 5 and new OS will be RHEL 7. Please do let me know.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You should ask this question here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is also a good place to start: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UPGRD/preup.htm#UPGRD12357

You may perform a direct upgrade to the new release if your current Oracle Database is release 10.2.0.5